# Need help understanding the friend command as well as how to get the == in my main to work

Tags: c++, stack, overflow

```
class Cspinner
{
    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & leftside, Cspinner rightside);

private:

    int randomSpin;
    string FruitName;

    int apple;
    int orange;
    int cherry;
    int banana;
    int peach;
    int fruit;

public:
    Cspinner()
    {
        randomSpin = 0;
        srand(time(NULL));
        apple = 30;
        orange = 25;
        cherry = 20;
        banana = 15;
        peach = 10;
    }

    Cspinner(int newapple, int neworange, int newcherry, int newbanana, int newpeach)
    {
        randomSpin = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        apple = newapple;
        orange = neworange;
        cherry = newcherry;
        banana = newbanana;
        peach = newpeach;

        srand(time(NULL));
    }


    void spin()
    {

        randomSpin = (rand() % 100) + 1;

        if (randomSpin <= peach)
        {
            FruitName = "peach ";
        }
        else if (randomSpin <= (peach + banana))
        {
            FruitName = "banana ";
        }
        else if (randomSpin <= (peach + banana + cherry))
        {
            FruitName = "cherry ";
        }
        else if (randomSpin <= (peach + banana + cherry + orange))
        {
            FruitName = "orange ";
        }
        else if (randomSpin <= (peach + banana + cherry + orange + apple))
        {
            FruitName = "apple ";
        }
    }


};

ostream & operator <<(ostream & leftside, Cspinner rightside) 
{
    leftside << rightside;
    return leftside;
}


void main()
{
    Cspinner w1;
    Cspinner w2;
    Cspinner w3(80, 5, 5, 5, 5);
    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        w1.spin();
        w2.spin();
        w3.spin();
        cout << w1 << w2 << w3;
        if (w1 == w2 && w2 == w3)
        {
            if (w1 == "Apple")    cout << "  (All Apples) ";
            else if (w1 == "Orange") cout << "  (All Oranges) ";
            else if (w1 == "Cherry") cout << "  (All Cherries) ";
            else if (w1 == "Banana") cout << "  (All Bananas) ";
            else  cout << "  (All Peaches)";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm creating the beginning of a slot machine here, however I am not too familiar with the friend command. I also can't figure out how to get friend to work with the == in the main run of the program. How would I link the two and get w1(w2, w3) to basically understand the string in the main so that I could see if all of the wheels/spinners lined up with each other?

Any help would be appreciated, I don't want the code itself, I want to understand what I'm doing wrong and how to associate with friend.

Comment: What problem do you have - i,e, what is not working? - What are you trying to use friend for? - when you make the "ostream & operator <<(..." a friend of CSpinner class it mean that function can access the internals of that class (i.e. private members), but you don't appear to be needing to do that in your code. Just a little more info needed : )

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using the `friend` keyword?

Comment: You should use `enum`erated types for the slots, and convert them to text when you output.  This will speed up your program and remove hassles of comparing "peach" to "pEaCh" or "PEACH".

Comment: Where is `operator==` defined for your class?  P.S. it doesn't need to be a friend.

Comment: `srand`/`rand` only has *one* state, not one for each of your objects...

Comment: I guess I don't need to use friend for this one? However I still need it so that the w's can access the strings of the fruitnames and compare themselves to it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `==` working in your `main` function, you need to perform two things:

- Change return type of `main`
- Implement `operator==` for your class.

The `main` function returns an `int` to the operating system, always.  You can return `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`.

### Implement `==` for a class

Here's the stencil for the `operator==` method:

```
bool operator==(const Mspinner& other) const
{
  bool is_equal = true;
  if (this != &other)
  {
    // Compare your data fields, for example:
    is_equal = FruitName == other.FruitName;
    is_equal = is_equal && (apple == other.apple);
    //...
  }
  return is_equal;
}
```